# Set checkbox value in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I'm trying to change the value of the checkbox with the `onChange` function of another input field.

I have something like this:

```
class price extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 20000,
            step: 1000,
            firstValue: null,
            secondValue: null,
            chcboxValue: false
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({firstValue: this.state.minValue, secondValue: this.state.maxValue});
    }

    handleChange(name, event) {
        let value = event.target.value;
        // We set the state value depending on input that is clicked
        if(name === "second") {
            if(parseInt(this.state.firstValue) < parseInt(value)) {
                this.setState({secondValue:value});
            }
        } else {
            // The first value can't be greater than the second value
            if(parseInt(value) < parseInt(this.state.secondValue)) {
                this.setState({firstValue: value});
            }
        }

        // We set the checkbox value
        if(parseInt(this.state.firstValue) != parseInt(this.state.minValue) || parseInt(this.state.secondValue) != parseInt(this.state.maxValue)) {
            this.setState({chcboxValue: true});
        } else {
            this.setState({chcboxValue: false});
        }
    }

    render() {
        const language = this.props.language;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="priceTitle">{language.price}</div>
                <InputRange language={language}
                            firstValue={parseInt(this.state.firstValue)}
                            secondValue={parseInt(this.state.secondValue)}
                            minValue={parseInt(this.state.minValue)}
                            maxValue={parseInt(this.state.maxValue)}
                            step={parseInt(this.state.step)}
                            handleChange={this.handleChange}
                            chcboxValue={this.state.chcboxValue}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My `InputRange` component is something like this:

```
const inputRange = ({language, firstValue, secondValue, minValue, maxValue, step, handleChange, chcboxValue}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="rangeValues">Range : {firstValue} - {secondValue}</div>
            <section className="range-slider">
                <input type="checkbox" checked={chcboxValue} />
                <input type="range" value={firstValue} min={minValue} max={maxValue} step={step}  onChange={handleChange.bind(this, "first")} />
                <input type="range" value={secondValue} min={minValue} max={maxValue} step={step} onChange={handleChange.bind(this, "second")} />
                <div className="minValue">{minValue}</div>
                <div className="maxValue">{maxValue}</div>
            </section>
        </div>
    );
};
```

The checkbox value on initial load is set to false. When the user changes the value of the price range slider, I want that the checkbox value to change to true.

When the user changes the value of the price range slider to their initial values (min and max values), I want the checkbox value to again change to false.

It isn't working in my example.

Any ideas?

Comment: you sure it is an OR ? (||) you say ```When user changes the values of the price range slider to their initial values (min and max values)```

Comment: If one of those values is not equal to min and max value, it means that user has changed the price slider, right?

Comment: If ONE is NOT equal (so say you change A but not B  A == initial value|| B == initial value would evaluate to TRUE, NOT changin A or B would result in the same, and only changing  both would return TRUE, therefore as you correctly say if ONE of them is not the initial one you don't want it to return TRUE, therefore it is an AND operator).

Besides I don't know if there are more errors in your code, but changing the || for && is a good start. :)

Comment: I want to return true if one of them is not the initial one. If min value == 0 and max value == 20000, and if Ais changed from 0 to 1000 and B is the same, thus 20000; then I want to change checkbox to true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is not working properly because you are checking the value before `this.setState()` is completed. Don't forget that `this.setState()` does not immediately mutate the `state`.

To fix it, you can create a function where you update the value of the checkbox

```
updateCheckBox(){
   if(parseInt(this.state.firstValue) != parseInt(this.state.minValue) || parseInt(this.state.secondValue) != parseInt(this.state.maxValue)){
        this.setState({chcboxValue: true});
    }else{
        this.setState({chcboxValue: false});
    }
}
```

and then pass it to your `handleChange` `this.setState()` calls.

```
handleChange(name, event){
    let value = event.target.value;
    //We set the state value depending on input that is clicked
    if(name === "second"){
        if(parseInt(this.state.firstValue) < parseInt(value)){
            this.setState({secondValue:value}, this.updateCheckBox);
        }
    }else{
        //The first value can't be greater than the second value
        if(parseInt(value) < parseInt(this.state.secondValue)) {
            this.setState({firstValue: value}, this.updateCheckBox);
        }
  }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/54479/)

Answer (score 13):

not sure but try it :

```
React.createElement('input',{type: 'checkbox', defaultChecked: false});
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.chkbox} onChange={this.handleChangeChk} />
```

or

```
var Checkbox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      isChecked: true
    };
  },
  toggleChange: function() {
    this.setState({
      isChecked: !this.state.isChecked // flip boolean value
    }, function() {
      console.log(this.state);
    }.bind(this));
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.state.isChecked}
          onChange={this.toggleChange} />
        Check Me!
      </label>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<Checkbox />, document.getElementById('checkbox'));
```

Answer (score 9):

we can set an `onChange` prop on the `input` field and handle the event.

App.js

```
import {useState} from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setIsChecked(event.target.checked);

    // ️ this is the checkbox itself
    console.log(event.target);

    // ️ this is the checked value of the field
    console.log(event.target.checked);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="checkbox-id"
        name="checkbox-name"
        onChange={handleChange}
        checked={isChecked}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of old but in case it helps.

I started relying on this syntax

Declare in the class, a variable to store the state:

```
const [agreeToAllTerms, setAgreeToAllTerms] = useState(false);
```

Declare the checkbox

```
<Checkbox checked={agreeToAllTerms} onChange={(event)=> {handleChangeChk(event)}}/>
```

And then in the function checked the current state of the checkbox like this.

```
const handleChangeChk = (chkValue) => {
    setAgreeToAllTerms(chkValue.target.checked);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic form change handler that also supports checkboxes

```
 onFormChange: (e) => {
    // In my example all form values are stored in a state property 'model'
    let model = this.state.model;

    if(e.target.type == 'checkbox') {

      if(model[e.target.name] === false) {
        model[e.target.name] = true;
      } else if(model[e.target.name] === true) {
        model[e.target.name] = false;
      } else {
        // if the property has not be defined yet it should be true
        model[e.target.name] = true;
      }
    } else {
      model[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    }

    // Update the state
    this.setState({
      model: model
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you shoud know how we can bind html input value in react. here this example for beginer. easy to understand

```
const chk= true

chkchk() ={ console.log("checkbox event fire")}
<input name="abc"
 type="checkbox"  checked={chk.toString()}        
 onChange={chkchk} 
            />
```